# How to check if hash keys match value from array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have:

```
arr = ['test', 'testing', 'test123']
ht = {"test": "abc", "water": "wet", "testing": "fun"}
```

How can I select the values in `ht` whose key matches `arr`?

```
ht_new = ht.select {|hashes| arr.include? hashes}
ht_new # => "{"test": "abc", "testing": "fun"}"
```

Additionally, how can we return values from:

```
arr = ["abc", "123"]
ht = [{"key": "abc", "value": "test"}, {"key": "123", "value": "money"}, {"key": "doremi", "value": "rain"}}]
output # => [{"key": "abc", "value": "test"}, {"key": "123", "value": "money"}]
```

Comment: What is your code `ht_new = ht.select {|hashes| arr.include? hashes}` intended to stand for? Is it your failed attempt? Or are you claiming that it returns `{"test": "abc", "testing": "fun"}`, which is a lie, since a key-value pair is compared with `arr`, and furthermore, no key in `ht` matches `arr` unless you convert from string to symbol?

Comment: The second `ht` is not valid Ruby expression. Your second question is also not clear.

Answer (score 4):

Only a slight change is needed:

```
ht.select { |k,_| arr.include? k.to_s }
  ##=> {:test=>"abc", :testing=>"fun"}
```

See [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select).

The block variable `_` (a valid local variable), which is the value of key `k`, signifies to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation. Some prefer writing that `|k,_v|`, or some-such.

Answer (score 2):

One option is mapping ([`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)) the keys in `arr`:

```
arr.map.with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = ht[k.to_sym] }

#=> {"test"=>"abc", "testing"=>"fun", "test123"=>nil}
```

If you want to get rid of pairs with `nil` value:

```
arr.map.with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = ht[k.to_sym] if ht[k.to_sym] }

#=> {"test"=>"abc", "testing"=>"fun"}
```

---

This is an option for the last request:

```
ht.select{ |h| h if h.values.any? { |v| arr.include? v} }
# or
arr.map { |e| ht.find { |h| h.values.any?{ |v| v == e } } }

#=> [{:key=>"abc", :value=>"test"}, {:key=>"123", :value=>"money"}]
```

Comment: May be better to use `reduce` here because OP doesn't want the keys that aren't found in the array

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks I see. I added a way to reject nil value. But I don't know how to with `reduce`?

Comment: Edit with an answer for the additional request

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way is:

```
 ht.slice(*arr.map(&:to_sym))
# => {:test => "abc", :testing => "fun"}
```